# Default value in useState not getting re-initialised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-state

I have a `snack bar component`, which displays a toast message for a few seconds and then disappears. I have an `App component` which contains a `button`, and on click of that `button`, I want to control the `snack bar component`. On the first click, the `snack bar` appears fine and disappears after the time specified is over. But when I click it again, the `snack bar` doesn't appear. I am initializing the `show state` to true every time, still, the `snack bar` isn't appearing. Please tell me where I am going wrong and how to rectify this. Below are the files. I am using a custom hook to control the behavior of snack bar's appearance.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Snackbar } from "./Snackbar";

function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setDisplay(true)}>Click me</button>
      {display && <Snackbar message="hello" />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Snackbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSnackbar } from "./useSnackbar";

const Snackbar = ({ message }) => {
  const { showSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  return (
    showSnackbar && (
      <div>
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export { Snackbar };
```

**useSnackbar.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useSnackbar = () => {
  const [showSnackbar, setSnackbar] = useState(true);
  const [snackbarMessage, setSnackbarMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setSnackbar(false);
      setSnackbarMessage('');
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [showSnackbar]);

  return {
    showSnackbar,
    setSnackbar,
    snackbarMessage,
    setSnackbarMessage
  };
};

export { useSnackbar };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't reset your `display` state in App.js

## Solution

Pass a reset state callback function to `Snackbar` to pass to the `useSnackbar` hook.

```
const useSnackbar = (onClose) => { // <-- callback function
  const [showSnackbar, setSnackbar] = useState(true);
  const [snackbarMessage, setSnackbarMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setSnackbar(false);
      setSnackbarMessage('');
      onClose && onClose(); // <-- invoke when timer expired
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      onClose && onClose(); // <-- edge case if component unmounts before expire
    };
  }, [onClose, showSnackbar]);

  return {
    showSnackbar,
    setSnackbar,
    snackbarMessage,
    setSnackbarMessage
  };
};

const Snackbar = ({ message, onClose }) => {
  const { showSnackbar } = useSnackbar(onClose); // <-- pass callback to hook
  return (
    showSnackbar && (
      <div>
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <div>
      <button onClick={() => setDisplay(true)}>Click me</button>
      {display && <Snackbar message="hello" onClose={() => setDisplay(false)} />} // <-- pass reset callback
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit default-value-in-usestate-not-getting-re-initialised]

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the `useSnackbar` hook has a default value of `true` for `showSnackbar` and it does get changed to `false` after 3 seconds but `display` in `App.js` stays `true` which means that even after the `timeout`.

Since `display` never gets set to `false`, `Snackbar` never gets unmounted so the state of `useSnackbar` never gets reinitialized.

My suggestion would be to change the structure of how `useSnackbar` is being used.

I'd move `useSnackbar` into `App.js` and set the snackbar open states there.

```
function App() {
  const { showSnackbar, setSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setSnackbar(true)}>Click me</button>
      {showSnackbar && <Snackbar message="hello" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const useSnackbar = () => {
  const [showSnackbar, setSnackbar] = useState(false);

  // rest of code
};
```

```
const Snackbar = ({ message }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{message}</p>
  </div>
);
```

**[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/snackbar-fbhmu?file=/src/Snackbar.js)**

There are other ways to structure thee components but for your example, this would be one of the simplest solutions.